Import JavaScript code from an npm package in order to use it programmatically
I have installed the htmlhint library that I can run in my command line over any HTML file like this:
npx htmlhint src/test-file.html

This lints the file and outputs some HTML errors (if any), for example:
   /Users/filipsavic/Documents/Programming/BM/Raven/code/src/component-library/widgets/HtmlEditor/test.html
      L1 |<html><body><div>asd <p>qw <span></span></p></div></body></html>
          ^ Doctype must be declared first. (doctype-first)

Scanned 1 files, found 1 errors in 1 files (5 ms)

I would like to use this library in my JavaScript/React files, something like this:
import htmlHint from 'htmlhint';

const parseRes = htmlHint('<html><body><span>some stuff...</span></body></html>');

How can I achieve this? Is there a general way to "convert" or "expose" the code from an npm package otherwise only/currently usable as a CLI command, so that it can be imported and the results of the CLI command used in a JavaScript program?

Don't think "run npx command programmatically", that's not at all what you're doing (and isn't possible in React/client-side code anyway). The CLI is (if the package is structured sensibly) just a wrapper around the core code you're trying to call directly (which may also not work in a web environment). Look at what that CLI entrypoint does, if the library doesn't have specific docs for its programmatic API.

I didn't know what better to name it... I see the javascript code for HTML linting in my node_modules, but I can't import it in my project files anywhere... that's what i am trying to do. Do you know if there's a way i can "expose" that core code so that I can import it and use programatically?

Renamed my question so that it's more clear what i'm trying to do

The documentation lists editor and task runner integrations. There is also an online demo/playground. Seems there should be a way to use the API without the CLI in between. But it doesn't seem to be explicitly listed.

Your question is now its own answer - yes, to use the JavaScript from an npm package programmatically you import it. How precisely you do that depends too specifically on each individual package, so again: look at how the package itself works, starting from the CLI entrypoint (bin in package.json). Some have docs around programmatic usage. If you've tried something specific and it doesn't work, give a [mre] (presumably what you've posted doesn't work, so: what does it do? What debugging have you done?)

Yeah, I thought there's a general way to "convert" or "expose" the code from an npm package otherwise only/currently usable a CLI command, so that it can be imported and the results of the CLI command used in a JavaScript program.
I'll do some digging. Thank you both jonrsharpe and VLAZ

Thanks for all the edits @jonrsharpe !!

Then: no. There are lots of ways to structure a package, in some cases (I would consider these bad design) the code may not be accessible in any way other than shelling out and invoking the CLI entrypoint.

Ok, but, if the code was made accessible, what "general" steps would one have to take in order to make that code accessible programatically as a import?

For my specific HTML linting problem, I found that the htmlhint library actually exposes a HTMLHint object that has verify method which does exactly what I was trying to achieve by invoking the CLI command programatically.
Code for linting/verifying HTML is as follows:
import { HTMLHint, HTMLParser } from 'htmlhint';



// somewhere in your component
const verificationResult = HTMLHint.verify('<html><body><div></body></html>');
console.log('verificationResult', verificationResult); // this logs the image below


